# How to skip 32/64bit-ness check in xxxConfigVersion.cmake

Tags: cmake

There is a header-only C++ library.
When I use `write_basic_package_version_file()`,
to create ...ConfigVersion.cmake file, 
not only version is checked but also 32/64 bitness compatibility:

```
# if the installed or the using project don't
# have CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P set, ignore it:
if("${CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P}" STREQUAL "" OR "8" STREQUAL "")
   return()
endif()

# check that the installed version has the 
# same 32/64bit-ness as the one which is currently searching:
if(NOT CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P STREQUAL "8")
  math(EXPR installedBits "8 * 8")
  set(PACKAGE_VERSION "${PACKAGE_VERSION} (${installedBits}bit)")
  set(PACKAGE_VERSION_UNSUITABLE TRUE)
endif()
```

This doesn't have any sense for header-only lib.
I can delete that code manually, but is there an elegant way not to generate this "addition"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you project unset the variable `CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P` (or set to an empty string) before calling `write_basic_package_version_file()` this would ensure the check for bitness is disabled.

Indeed, the following snippet used on all `BasicConfigVersion-*.in` templates:

```
# if the installed or the using project don't have CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P set, ignore it:
if("${CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P}" STREQUAL "" OR "@CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P@" STREQUAL "")
    return()
endif()
```

would be configured as

```
if("${CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P}" STREQUAL "" OR "" STREQUAL "")
    return()
endif()
```

and always return.

Comment: Thanks, that is a very simple solution and it works!